# ImportError: cannot import name 'sync_playwright' from 'playwright'

Tags: python, api, playwright-python, tiktok

When i start this code i had this error python 3.7 `[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Y7H.png)

```
import TikTokApi
api = TikTokApi.get_instance(use_selenium=True, executablePath="C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application")`
user = api.user(username="therock")`
for video in user.videos():
      print(video.id)

for liked_video in api.user(username="public_likes").videos():
      print(liked_video.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to upgrade playwright, try running

```
pip install playwright --upgrade
```